# SetCookie массив php

Tags: php

Как в PHP в setCookie() передать массив?

Comment: Сериализовать его

Comment: @asd, размер кук ограничен и не такой уж и большой.

Answer (score 2):

Через [serialize](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) как вариант

```
setcookie('cookie', serialize($array), time()+86400);
```

Answer (score 2):

Или через [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php), если хотите эти данные прочитать из JavaScript

```
setcookie('cookie', json_encode($array), time()+86400);
```